# How modify 'HelloWorld' code to multiply two numbers instead of change text

Tags: objective-c, ios

What is causing the 'Expected identifier' error on line 3 below?

```
-(IBAction)changeGreeting:(id)sender {

  self.userName = self.textField.text;
  float amount = [[self.textField.text] floatValue];  **! Expected identifier**
  // float amount = [[self.userName] floatValue];

  NSString *nameString = self.userName;
  if ([nameString length] == 0) {
      nameString = @"World";
  }

  NSString *greeting = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Hello, %@!", nameString];
  self.label.text = greeting;
}
```

Can I do the text conversion to float, double the value & display it within this same button action method?

I am new to OOP programming. Any tips greatly appreciated.
Walter

Comment: Which programming language is this? Please tag your post accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is:

```
[self.textField.text]
```

You do not need to put the `[ ]` because you are not calling a method, you was supposed to just call it this way:

```
[self.textField.text floatValue]
```

You will just need to use the `[ ]` when you want to call a method.